# Subdividing Vector - Unsure How to Handle (const) Iterators?

Tags: c++, vector, split

I have been trying to subdivide a vector. Basically, my goal is to split up the initial vector (nVector) into smaller vectors, on which successive sorts are applied. Eventually, an element K will be selected from the final sorted subvector. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to implement the following algorithm from my head.

I want to, at any point j in the vector, start the subvector from that point to the end of the vector. However, implementing it has given me a headache trying to get the iterators to agree, and I get "invalid conversion from const int* const' to int* errors. I am not sure how to handle this since to my understanding, iterators must be constant. Code below.

```
int subVectorize() {

vector<int> subVector(M);

int j = 0;
for (unsigned int z = 0; z < nVector.size();  z++)
{

vector<int>::const_iterator start = nVector.begin() + z;
vector<int>::const_iterator end = nVector.begin() + z + M - 1;

if (end <= nVector.end()){

    for (vector<int>::iterator i = start; i <= end ; i++) {
        subVector.at(j) = *i;
        j++;
    }

    j = 0;
    cVector[z] = sortReturn(M, K, subVector);
 }

else {
    end -= nVector.size();
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = start; i <= nVector.end() ; i++) {
        subVector.at(j) = *i;
        j++;
    }
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = nVector.begin(); i <= end; i++) {
        subVector.at(j) = *i;
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    cVector[z] = sortReturn(M, K, subVector);
}
}

int* finalArray = new int[N];

for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {

finalArray[i] = cVector[i];
}

quickSort (finalArray, 0, N);

return finalArray[0];

}
```

Comment: Have you considered implementing your function purely in terms of iterators? Then you can call your function with iterators pointing to different beginning and end ranges.

Comment: Doing so does not absolve me of the const iterator/iterator conflicts. I have tried initializing j instead as vector<int>::iterator j = subVector.begin(); to the same result.